# How to have a ScrollView row take up full screen height on tap gesture?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to have a ScrollView of content and when tapping on a row, I want the row's height (bottom and top) to animate to take the full screen height.  I tried the following with no success:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedRow: Int? = nil

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(0..<10, id: \.self) { row in
                HStack {
                    Text("Row \(row)")
                }
                .frame(minHeight: self.selectedRow == row ? 0 : 50, maxHeight: self.selectedRow == row ? .infinity : 50)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1))
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.selectedRow = row
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work like I was hoping and doesn't take the full screen height.

Is this the wrong approach?  Is it better to make it navigate to a new view and have it animate into the new view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scroll views always try to size the content with the smallest height (in the case of a vertical scroll view). If they used the max size, and it was `.infinite`, they would be infinitely long.

Instead you should use a `GeometryReader` to get the size of the view that contains the scroll view, and use the explicit height of the size of the scroll view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedRow: Int? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(0..<10, id: \.self) { row in
                    HStack {
                        Text("Row \(row)")
                    }
                    .frame(height: selectedRow == row ? reader.size.height : 50)
                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.selectedRow = row
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: amazing, this is the behavior I am looking for!  I appreciate you explaining!